# Login form in Swagger c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger

Is there any way to configure Swagger so that authentication takes place through a login and password, where they are passed to my authentication method and receive a jwt token, which would then be written to the header
There is my some code

Auth controller method

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> LoginAsync([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto)
{
    var response = await _userService.LoginAsync(loginDto);

    return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, response);
}
```

My request DTO

```
public class LoginDto
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Auth response DTO

```
public class AuthResponseDto
{
    public UserDto User { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use OpenApiSecurityScheme, but I didn't really understand how to do exactly what I want

Comment: Swagger is about web-service metadata, it has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: _"so that authentication takes place through a login and password, where they are passed to my authentication method and receive a jwt token, which would then be written to the header"_ - Browser-based applications and SPAs use Cookies instead of HTTP `Authorize:` header Bearer tokens. Previously SPAs did (try) to use HTTP header bearer tokens but due to all the intractable security issues everyone is moving back to cookies. `Authorize:` header tokens should only be used by headless/non-interactive clients.